# Replacing parentheses of mathematical functions, leaving other parentheses

Tags: ruby, regex

How do I write a regular expression to replace all parentheses of mathematical functions by bracket, but leave out all other parentheses?

Here are some sample inputs:

```
x(n)+(y(n)+1)*n
x(n(a,b),a,b)+2^(y(n(a,b)+a+b)+1)
x(n)+(y(n)/(N(n)))
```

and I want their corresponding outputs to be:

```
x[n]+(y[n]+1)*n
x[n[a,b],a,b]+2^(y[n[a,b]+a+b]+1)
x[n]+(y[n]/(N[n]))
```

This is what I managed to scribble.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mechanize'
CSV.open('C:\Users\hp1\Desktop\output.txt', "wb") do |index|
    f = File.open('C:\Users\hp1\Desktop\input.txt', "r")
    f.each_line { |line|
        fn = line
        fn=fn.gsub(/(?[a-zA-Z0-9])\[+-*"/",]/, /[?[a-zA-Z0-9]]\[+-*"/",]/)
        index<<line
    end
 }
end
```

But it's not working.

**EDIT**: A function means anything of the form `f(x)`, `f(x,y)`, etc. Non-functions are of the form `x+y`, `x*y` etc. So, an expression `f(x(y)+m(n)+(a+b))` needs to be transformed into `f[x[y]+m[n]+(a+b)]`.

Comment: You need to show your attempt (you risk gathering downvotes in no time in here if you don't)

Comment: When are parentheses of mathematical function and when are they not? What is the format of a mathematical function?

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski done.

Comment: There is a difference in a specification and  an example.

Comment: @sawa @Meier A function means anything of the form `f(x)`, `f(x,y)`, etc. Non-functions are of the form `x+y`, `x*y` etc. So, an expression `f(x(y)+m(n)+(a+b))` needs to be transformed into `f[x[y]+m[n]+(a+b)]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use a simple loop, and replace the nested pairs of parentheses from inside out.

```
s = "x(n)+(y(n)+1)*n\nx(n(a,b),a,b)+2^(y(n(a,b)+a+b)+1)\nx(n)+(y(n)/(N(n)))\nf(x(y)+m(n)+(a+b))"

while  s.gsub!(/(\w+)\(([^()]+)\)/, '\1[\2]')
  s.gsub!(/(\W)\(([^()]+)\)/, '\1{\2}')
end

s.gsub!(/{/, "(")
s.gsub!(/}/, ")")

puts s
# x[n]+(y[n]+1)*n
# x[n[a,b],a,b]+2^(y[n[a,b]+a+b]+1)
# x[n]+(y[n]/(N[n]))
# f[x[y]+m[n]+(a+b)]
```

I assume that any sequence of word characters followed by an opening parenthesis is a function name.

The temporary substitution of `()` to `{}` inside the *while* loop is required to get grouping parentheses that occur inside function arguments out of the way. This is reversed after all function substitutions `f()` to `f[]` are done.

Comment: Thanks. What is the meaning of this part though: `'\1[\2]'`

Comment: \1 is the first matching result (the function name), \2 the second one (the arguments). Note the single quotes. You have to write \\1 when using double quotes. The brackets are inserted literally.

Comment: According to the OP's edit `f(x(y)+m(n)+(a+b))` needs to be transformed into `f[x[y]+m[n]+(a+b)]`, which goes against your assumption. (But it is not your fault since the OP has not made it clear initially).

Comment: Didn't see that. Fixed. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I suggest matching all nested `(...)` after *word* characters (or even `[a-zA-Z]` followed with `\w*` to match valid identifiers), and then replace all `(` with `[` and `)` with `]` inside a gsub block.

See the [regex demo](http://rubular.com/r/OA6oz2tsCH) and the [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/VWWe7N):

```
strs = ['x(n)+(y(n)+1)*n', 'x(n(a,b),a,b)+2^(y(n(a,b)+a+b)+1)', 'x(n)+(y(n)/(N(n)))']
strs.each { |s| 
    puts s.gsub(/\b[a-zA-Z]\w*(\((?>[^()]|\g<1>)*\))/) { |m| m.gsub(/\(/,"[").gsub(/\)/,"]") }
}
```

In your code:

```
fn=fn.gsub(/\b[a-zA-Z]\w*(\((?>[^()]|\g<1>)*\))/) { |m| m.gsub(/\(/,"[").gsub(/\)/,"]") }
```

Result:

```
x[n]+(y[n]+1)*n
x[n[a,b],a,b]+2^(y[n[a,b]+a+b]+1)
x[n]+(y[n]/(N[n]))
```

The regex explanation:

- `\b[a-zA-Z]\w*` - a word boundary followed with an ASCII letter  followed with zero or more word characters (`[a-zA-Z0-9_]`)
- `(\((?>[^()]|\g<1>)*\))` - Group 1 matching:

  - `\(` - a literal `(`
  - `(?>[^()]|\g<1>)*` - an atomic group matching either symbol(s) other than `(` and `)` or the whole Group 1 subpattern (with the subroutine call `\g<1>`)
  - `\)` - a closing literal `)`

Answer (score -1):

Not possible with classical regular expressions alone. Mathematical expressions can be nested in infinite depth, but regular expressions are using a finite state machine. 
(The notion of an indefinite depth is course an abstraction. As such, it is very valuable to helps you to decide between different complexities. In practice, these means the "normal" regular expression you need gets bigger depending how many levels of nesting you are willing to support. It can get very fast out of control.)

You need something like a stack to store the number of open parentheses, so when a closing parentheses appears you need to match it somehow with the open parentheses to decide it if need to be replaces or not.

***Edit:***
I have now learned that modern regular expressions (like in ruby 2) can have recursive subroutines. With this you should be able to solve problem of the nesting. So my claim that is is impossible is no longer true.

Comment: Nope. 1. No (explicitly written) mathematical expression can be nested in infinite depth. That is physically impossible. 2. Modern regular expressions are not using a finite state machine. The term "regular" in regular expression is just a historical artefact.

Comment: But the depth is potentially infinite, you can not give an upper limit. .

Comment: @sawa re 1.: he probably meant arbitrarily deep. Re 2.: And yet matching parentheses is something regexes explicitly _can't_ do. Except maybe in one flavor or few, and you lose readability quickly.

Comment: @JanDvorak: Readability level depends on who reads the regex pattern and how well it is explained in the documentation. Also, Ruby Oniguruma-flavor regex engine supports recursion.

Comment: @JanDvorak 1. That may be the case, but Meier actually didn't use that word. Infinite and arbitrary are completely different things. 2. You are clearly wrong about that. At least, this question is about Ruby, and you should naturally assume the regex engine used in Ruby, which is Oniguruma/Onigmo.

Comment: @Meier Yes, you cannot give an upper limit, but the depth is not potentially infinite.